# When I set the 'required' property to 'true' the widget validation is not working

Tags: javascript, dojo

The widget seems to work as expected because the margin gets highlighted when I click inside/outside the textbox.
However when I set the `required` property the borders are not becoming red.

```
var widget = getWidget("id"); 
widget.required = true;
```

Is there any to change a property for dijit widget(TextBox) ?

Comment: Please reformat you question properly. Here you can find more details on how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to sue the setter for that:

```
getWidget("id").set("required", true);
```

Otherwise you change the property but the widget is not aware that property have changed